# Using bash's `/dev/udp`, how would I know if the port was open?

Tags: bash, networking, devices

I do not have access to `netcat` or `nmap` so I'm trying to use `bash` and the `/dev/udp/` special files to test ports.

I could do something like:

```
echo "" > /dev/udp/example.com/8000
```

But `$?` is always `0` when using UDP. I'm assuming that's because that is the return value of the `echo ""` command correct?

I am basically trying to replicate what I am able to do with `nmap` and `netcat`:

```
nmap -sU -p 8000 example.com | grep open >/dev/null && echo 'open'
nc -z -u example.com 8000 && echo 'open'
```

How would I do this with `/dev/udp`?

Comment: UDP doesn't guarantee delivery, so even if bash thinks it's succeeded in sending the message, the message may have been destroyed on the way. How did you test an unsuccessful sending (not an unsuccessful connection: UDP isn't a connection)?

Answer (score 14):

For tcp, just checking `$?`. If connection failed, `$?` won't be `0`:

```
$ >/dev/tcp/google.com/81
bash: connect: Network is unreachable
bash: /dev/tcp/google.com/81: Network is unreachable
$ echo $?
1
```

It will take time for `bash` to realize that the connection failed. You can use [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) to trigger `bash`:

```
$ timeout 1 bash -c '>/dev/tcp/google.com/80' &&
  echo Port open ||
  echo Port close
Port open
```

---

Testing udp port is more complex.

Strictly speaking, there is no *open* state (of course, udp is *stateless* protocol) with udp. There're only two states with udp, *listening* or *not*. If the state is *not*, you will get an [ICMP Destination Unreachable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Destination_unreachable).

Unfortunately, firewall or router often drop those ICMP packets, so you won't be sure what state of udp port.

Comment: Rephrased my question to focus on UDP. My apologies for the ninja edit. I thought it would be similar so did not make the distinction. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 11):

In general, you can't.

Unlike TCP, UDP is connectionless.  You can't detect that a port is open simply by making a do-nothing connection to it like you can with TCP.  Rather, you need to send data to the port and see what happens, and the details of UDP as implemented in the real world make interpreting the results difficult.  Even sophisticated packet-level tools like `nmap` can't tell for certain if there's a program listening to a given UDP port.  `nmap` classifies UDP ports into three groups:

1. Definitely open.  Sending a packet to the port elicited a data response from the destination machine.
2. Definitely closed.  Sending a packet to the port elicited a "ICMP Destination Unreachable" message from the destination machine.
3. Either open or filtered.  Sending a packet to the port elicited no response whatsoever.  Maybe there's a firewall that's dropping the packets; maybe there's a program listening and `nmap` just hasn't figured out how to get a response; maybe the user just got unlucky and all the packets were lost in transit.

Comment: Great information about `nmap`. Thanks, this clarifies a lot of confusion.