# Test for open TCP port in bash script

Tags: shell-script, networking, tcp

I want to delay the script execution until a certain server process is ready, which it is once it accepts incoming TCP connections.

How do I test if a local TCP port is open (I get a SYN/ACK answer)?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191658/38906

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `lsof` if available for this purpose. You can `grep` the output to check for a line of output with a `LISTEN` condition for the port in question. Some options may have to be passed to prevent converting port names to symbolic, etc, see `man lsof` for details.